# How to Create an extension in zend framework 2 and call through hooks in view

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am quite new to zend framework-2 i am working on a web app in zend framework 2. I want to know if its possible to create extensions or plugins and attach them to hooks and call those hooks in view templates as we can do in wordpress or prestashop ?

Any response is highly appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: not sure if view helper can help to achive this actually i think that approcah will be very clear if i can code this way in zend but please suggest me the most clean way i have blocks like login block with fb and twitter things like that i was getting into extensions like in wordpress

Comment: Updated my answer. I suspect that what you _actually_ need is a well written partial view script. You can create these as standalone views, embed them into any view script you need, passing the data to it. Think of partials as something in between parts of a view script that you `include`, and regular functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*
In response to your comment. It turns out you have certain *"blocks"* of code you want to use in your view. That, to me at least, sounds like [a partial view-script](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html).
To which, of course, the explanation below still applies (no logic, apart from the odd loop and `if`, etc...)

---

I think you're confusing *extensions* and *plugins* with *view-helpers*. In wordpress and other blog/CMS systems that are in common use, little add-ons are often referred to as extensions or plugins.
Zend Framework has plugins, too, but I don't think that that's what you're looking for.

I take it you're actually looking for [zend view helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html)
A couple of these helpers are part of the ZendFW as is, but you can extend the abstract helper quite easily to create your own. After that, it's a simple matter of passing that helper to the view, and you're all set.

If you *are* indeed looking for [ZendFW plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html), then I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree. Sure: these things exist, and of course you can create your own. But to use these kinds of plugins from within the *view*? No, that would be a crime against everything MVC is about.
The basic layout of any MVC framework/application is such that the controller does the initial processing of the request, the Model ***layer*** (== data-models, DB connection, DataProviders, Services... the works) takes care of the actual logic & computing. When this layer (sometimes referred to as the business layer) is done, it returns the results to the controller.
The controller might do some simple prepping, but then passes on the data to the view.

Once the data is passed to the view, all that is left to do is *representing the data* (most of the time, this is building a page). Any logic that is more complex than a simple `if (empty($this->foo)) { echo 'No data';} else { echo $this->foo; }` of a loop is ***bad practice***

ZendFW's plugins can be used to authenticate users, redirect clients if a cookie/session has expired, and even set headers so on. Not something you'd want to do in the view.